# Multiple values in switch case / converting ifs to switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a big list of Ifs, and I want to change it into a switch statement. Currently it looks like this:

```
if(x == 1){
    ...
}
if(x == 2){
    ...
}
if(myArray.contains(x)){
    ...
}
```

In actuality it's a bit longer than this, but it's the third if in the example that confuses me - how do I change that around to get it to work in a switch, or is it even possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could do something like this, but YMMV according to possible exit conditions in your code:

```
switch (x) {
case 1: 
  ...
  break;
case 2:
  ...
  break;
case 3:
case 4:
  ... multi-case
  break;
default:
  if(myArray.contains(x)){
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This is also slightly different: switch/case is a `if` ... `else if`. In the siutation where x is modified in a "then" block statement, the overall behaviour will be different.

Comment: Unlike the first two ifs in the question, the third can still be true even if one of the preceding ones is also true. `x` can't be equal to `1` AND `2` at the same time, but it can be equal to `1` and contained within `myArray` at the same time. Moving the if statement into the `case` statements `default` is likely not the correct solution.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified - the values in the array will never match anything else that I'm checking for, so it's not an issue. good catch though.

Comment: You're both right, that's why I told YMMV... I assumed that the code in every if had an exit. Orelse the original code looks like a plate of spaghettis. Multiple ifs, each modifying the variable for itself and the next if, no elsif, a final condition that seems logically unrelated. The meaning of the original code is far from clear, so there's no straightforward translation for it. My answer provide a possible solution, but only the original poster will know if it suits his needs.

Answer (score 3):

Switch statement can be used only to test equality of x

So if `not equality conditions` like (`if(myArray.contains(x))`) must come at the end, then you can copy paste this into default section of switch

It would look this way

```
    switch (x) {
     case 1:   ...; break;
     case 2:   ...; break;
     default: if(myArray.contains(x)) ...
    }
```

If `not equality conditions` would need to be in the middle, then its not possible to use switch.

reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 1):

You can only swith over the x value. That means the last condition will not be part of the switch:

```
switch(x) {
case 1:
    ...
    break;
case 2:
    ...
    break;
}
if(myArray.contains(x)){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. The switch statement will make it a little cleaner and easier to maintain. You have to worry about `x` because it has to be compile-time constant.

```
switch(x) {
 case 1:
    doSomething();
    break();
 case 2:
    doSomethingElse();
    break();

default:
 if(myArray.contains(x)){

 }


//etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look very Object Oriented.

Try to refactor your code with "Replace conditional with polymorphism"
http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html

A map can help you to do some lookups, if you need to convert from int to custom object.